# what is the point of the overloading of the method sort in class Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-8

I find that the method `sort()` in class `Arrays` is not the same because of type of parameter, but some logic is the same.

Such as when the parameter is `long` ,the method is the same as the parameter is `Integer`. So what is the point of overloading the method. In other words, the code maybe shorter but why is it designed to be so long?

Comment: There is no `sort` method where “the parameter is long”. Don’t confuse `long` with `long[]`.

Answer (score 3):

> when the parameter is long ,the method is the same as the parameter is integer.

It's not `int` and `long`, but `int[]` and `long[]`. It's important.

For instance, there are widening primitive conversions for `int` and `long`.

```
int i = 10;
long l = i;
```

However, `int[]` and `long[]` is absolutely different types and similar handy conversions aren't supported. In order to pass an `int[]` to a `method(long[])`, you have to do the conversion `int[]` to `long[]` manually.

```
int[] iA = {10, 10};
long[] lA = Arrays.stream(iA).asLongStream().toArray();
```

From the perspective of a good API, it's not convenient. The idea is to let the user work with the type they've got initially and not to force them for manual (usually, error-prone) conversions. So the point is **convenience**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have integer arrays `int[]` you cannot pass them to `Arrays#sort(long[])` (and vice versa) because they're different types. Thus, you need method signatures for all primitive array types. Also, there is no common super-type that could be used as the parameter type.

Counterquestion: If you don't overload the `#sort` method, what parameter types would you suggest to use for the `#sort` method so that you can pass both `int[]` and `long[]` types to sort?

---

*// Update after your question in comments regarding casting:*

No, you cannot cast from `int[]` to `long[]` or vice versa. The following code will **not** compile:

```
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3};

Arrays.sort((long[]) myIntArray); // COMPILE ERROR
```

What you can do is the following (requires Java 8):

```
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2, 3};
long[] myCastedArray = Arrays.stream(myIntArray).asLongStream().toArray();

Arrays.sort(myCastedArray); // #sort(long[])
```

---

By the way, although you stated that the answer of Andrew Tobilko doesn't help you, you should try to understand what he's telling you. I also think that you make sure to understand the difference between `int/long` (primitive) and `int[]/long[]` (array of primitive).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but is long not OK? if the array is `int[]` ,is casting to `long` OK?

Answer (score -1):

Because the type of elements are different you need to implement the `sort` method accordingly.

The keyword is **polymorphism** ;)